# Why can't I get wget to pipe standard output to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, gnu

When I run this command it works as expected:

```
wget -p https://www.google.com/
```

After running this command I check the error code with

```
echo $?
```

This returns 0, indicating that last command ran without experiencing any errors.

Now I run:

```
wget -p https://www.google.com/ >/dev/null
```

This last command should suppress standard output- but it doesn't. So what is going on? This almost seems particular to wget, because I've never had an issue piping standard output before with other commands.

It's also worth noting that if you run:

```
wget -p https://www.google.com/ 2>/dev/null
```

all output is suppressed. Would someone care to enlighten a confused human?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `wget -p https://www.google.com/ &> /dev/null` is working. That is because `wget` output to stderr instead of stdout. You could check wget [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html).

> **‘--output-file=logfile’**
>
> Log all messages to logfile. The messages are normally reported to standard error.

Comment: Or just use `-q`.